# mysql reports: count unique login per day

Tags: mysql, count, report, date-format

I've (as example) a mysql table "logins" with this content:

```
user_id | last_login
1       | 2015-02-01 05:01:07
1       | 2015-02-01 12:42:09
2       | 2015-02-01 22:16:23
2       | 2015-02-02 15:45:23
2       | 2015-02-04 21:27:04
3       | 2015-02-04 06:25:45
4       | 2015-02-05 03:12:01
```

My question is: how can I generate a summery of all unique users per day. So I'll a report like this:

```
day        | count
2015-02-01 | 2
2015-02-02 | 1
2015-02-04 | 2
2014-02-05 | 1
```

This query is NOT working:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( login_date, '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS `day`
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) AS count, DATE_FORMAT( login_date, '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS `sdate` WHERE `sdate` = day )
FROM `logins`
GROUP BY `day`
ORDER BY `day` // query not working.....
```

How can I get a SQL summery of all unique users per day...?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the alias name in the "group by" and "order by" clause. This query will give your report:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(`last_login`, '%Y-%m-%d') as theDate, 
count(distinct(user_id)) as theCount from logins 
group by theDate 
order by theCount;
```

Hope this helps.